# _TypeError (type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'bool') Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, conditional-operator, flutter-futurebuilder, listtile

I'm wanting to change the border according to the selected address of a card in Flutter, I did a check with a ternary operator, and a method that returned either true or false, but it returns an error:

`_TypeError (type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'bool')`

Code:

```
_getAddressSelected(address) async {
    SharedPreferences pref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var adressSelected = await pref.getInt('address_selected_id');

    if (address.id == addressSelected) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

```
child: Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
    child: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: listAddress.length,
        itemBuilder: (ctx, i) {
            return Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
                child: ListTile(
                    onTap: () => _selectAddress(listAddress[i]),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                        side: _getAddressSelected(listAddress[i])
                            ? const BorderSide(color:Color(0xFFE84505))
                            : const BorderSide(color:Color(0xffD0D0D0))
                         ),
```

I've tried several times and it doesn't work!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `FutureBuilder` while `_getEnderecoSelecionado` is a future method.

```dart
FutureBuilder<bool>(
  future: _getEnderecoSelecionado(
      _getEnderecoSelecionado(listaEndereco[i])), //use state variable for statefulWidget
  builder: (context, snapshot) => Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
    child: ListTile(
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          side: snapshot.data ?? false
              ? const BorderSide(color: Color(0xFFE84505))
              : const BorderSide(color: Color(0xffD0D0D0))),
    ),
  ),
)
```

You might do it on top level instead of here, Try to follow the [doc example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html)

Comment: I put an additional part of the code above and translated the methods for you to understand better, I tried to read your code but I was a little confused, could you reread it and see if it continues in this logic?

Comment: Use  Padding `child:FutureBuilder...`

Comment: I tried to do it this way, but the listAddress would stop working, by removing the ListTile